# Problems with css file

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to have:

```
Jake J.
Matt D.
Kate K.
Matt H. ...
```

And here is my code

```
renderNames(){
   const names =[
     "Jake J.",
     "Matt D."
     ...
   ]
   names.map((name,i) = > 
      return ( 
        <div><b className = 'b' + i>{name}</b></div>
   )
   return names;
}
```

I have a list of ten names that I want to show. What I wanted to do is to create 10 classNames b1,b2 ... and then to give them all different values for top and left. But I don't think it is such a good idea, because if I want to change something in my code I will have to manually edit all values. So is there a prettier way to do this. I'm using Meteor + React + TypeScript + CSS.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the left and top values? Wouldn't one class suffice on the children and a wrapper for all of them within which you can use child selectors and style them as you need? Or maybe an even better idea would be a flex layout, but a little more information is needed to be able to tell.

Comment: I have a section and in this section I want to show this 10 names. Using left and top in the css file (ex left0 : 50px top0: 50 then for the next one top1: 50+50px and so on ) I give the position of the element. ps I'm new to css

Comment: Doing absolute positioning like that on a list seems really weird. You just make every item 50px tall and let them automatically stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
renderNames(){
   const names =[
     "Jake J.",
     "Matt D."
     ...
   ]
   names.map((name,i) = > 
      return ( 
        <p><b className='name'>{name}</b></p>
   )

   return (
     <div className='container'> 
        {names} 
     </div>);
}
```

Should work for you. Then in your stylesheet you can style `.container` and `.container .name`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for css styles, then I agree with your concerns. 
Do you know css selector `nth-child` ? 
I would add className to parent div. And then in styles do something like this:

```
.parent:nth-child(0) { ... } 
... 
.parent:nth-child(9) { ... }
```

then you can simply style your items from css.